Ошибка при установке playwright через пакетный менеджер npm
C:\Users\sherzodjon.abdumutal>npm install playwright
npm error code E403
npm error 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.yarnpkg.com/playwright
npm error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm error 403 on a server you do not have access to.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sherzodjon.abdumutal\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-25T10_18_30_023Z-debug-0.log

